# How to save multiple location coordinates in your project?

Tags: java, android, location, maps, android-volley

I'm fetching some of the locations from the server and need to point them as markers in the google map, so what i did was i created a model of the locations and used the volley library to fetch the details from the server and saved them in a variable and post it in the map. But I'm getting an error as **java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points**. 
So need some assistance.
This is my model

```
public class LocationModel
private String pdLatitude;
private String pdLongitude;

public LocationModel(String pdLatitude, String pdLongitude){
this.pdLatitude = pdLatitude;
this.pdLongitude = pdLongitude; }

public String getPdLatitude() {
return pdLatitude;
}

public String getPdLongitude() {
return pdLongitude;
}
```

This is my Activity where i'm retreiving the information from the server

```
private void findRoute(){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                Constant.Route_URL + "/" + driverschoolname + "/" + driverid,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        String pdlatitude = "";
                        String pdlongitude = "";
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("res");
                            for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                StudentsPickDropModel pickDropModel = new StudentsPickDropModel(
                                        object.getString("pdloc_latitude"),
                                        object.getString("pdloc_longitude")
                                );
                                pdlatitude += pickDropModel.getPdLatitude();
                                pdlongitude += pickDropModel.getPdLongitude();
                                Toast.makeText(StudentsPickDropActivity.this, pickDropModel.getPdName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, GetRoute.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pd_latitude", pdlatitude);
                                intent.putExtra("pd_longitude", pdlongitude);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

And this is how i'm posting my coordiantes in Google maps

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        schoollat = bundle.getString("school_lat");
        schoollng = bundle.getString("school_lng");
        pdlat = bundle.getString("pd_latitude");
        pdlng = bundle.getString("pd_longitude");

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                Location location = task.getResult();
                if (location == null){
                    requestNewLocationData();
                } else {
                    currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                    currentLng = location.getLongitude();
                    System.out.println("Current Latitude: "+location.getLatitude());
                    System.out.println("Current Longitude: "+location.getLongitude());
                }
            }
        });

        Double clat = currentLat;
        System.out.println("Current Latitude : "+clat);

        Double schoollatitude = new Double(schoollat);
        Double schoollongitude = new Double(schoollng);
        System.out.println("School latitude : "+schoollatitude + ", School Longitude : "+schoollongitude);
        Double pdlatitude = new Double(pdlat);
        Double pdlongitude = new Double(pdlng);

        getDirections = findViewById(R.id.getdirection);
        getDirections.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new FetchURL(GetRoute.this).execute(getUrl(placeOne.getPosition(), placeTwo.getPosition(), "driving"), "driving");
            }
        });

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        places = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(pdlatitude, pdlongitude)).title("Office");
```

And this is my JSON

```
  "res": [
        {
            "pdloc_latitude": "12.3111356",
            "pdloc_longitude": "76.6075989",
        },
        {
            "pdloc_latitude": "88.568645787",
            "pdloc_longitude": "75.54544454887",
        }
```

Comment: Which line cause that exception?

Comment: Double pdlatitude = new Double(pdlat);

Comment: Please log your pdlat. Maybe something wrong with this value.

Comment: Its merging both the latitude -> PDlat : 12.311135688.568645787

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.parseDouble()` for better efficiency

> The core method is parseDouble() which is specially designed to parse
>   a String containing floating point value into the Double object. Rest
>   of the methods e.g. valueOf() and constructor uses parseDouble()
>   internally.

and be sure that the `pdlat` value you are passing is a valid double number and not just plain characters

This( `Double.parseDouble()`) method will throw **NullPointerException** if the string you are passing is null and **NumberFormatException** if `String` is not containing a valid double value e.g. containing alphabetic characters.

Just debug `Double pdlatitude = new Double(pdlat);` line to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your PDlat have 2 points. That is invalid for Double since Double have 1 point.

Your value:

```
12.311135688.568645787
```

What it should has 1 point like this:

```
12.311135688568645787
```

PS. You can catch an exception If the value parsing is fail, and what to do is up to what exception occurs.